# how to put my own image instead of mediastore.images.media.data?

Tags: android

How Can I put image from directory instead of load from media. I load from gallery like this
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };. How can load from /assets or /drawable-mdpi ? This is my code. Kindly tell me how can i used this code to add image from my directory?

```
public class ImageGalleryDemoActivity extends Activity {

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the respective drawables in the android drawables folders and Android would automatically choose the required drawable based upon the device display density. You can set the drawables as

```
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image));
```

You can also take help from [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDrawables/article.html).

Comment: I add the code above. See and tell me that how I edit this code to take images from drawable-mdpi?